# Pdo BindValue with char '&'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with my pdo request.
My request works (I tried it directly with phpMyAdmin), but when $name contains char "&", it seems that bindValue doesn't work.

```
public static function get_by_name($name, $project_id)
{
    $statement = Element::$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE name = :name AND project_id = :project_id');
    $statement->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(':project_id', $project_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $result =  $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result)
        return $result;
    else
        return null;
}
```

I echoed the value of $name in my function and the value is right.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: look at the page source im guessing your `&` is actually `&amp;` which is why its not working

Comment: @cmorrissey I added $name = htmlspecialchars_decode($name); at the beginning of my function and now it's working. Do you think it's a good solution ? Anyway thank you really much.

Comment: yes that's a good solution